# Apply bin limits from one data frame to another data frame in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, binning

I am trying to create bins with equal amounts of observations using an initial data frame:

```
# create data frame
das <- data.frame(anim=1:15, count = 1,
              wt=c(181,179,180.5,201,201.5,245,246.4,
                   189.3,301,354,369,205,199,394,231.3))

## create 3 equal bins
das$bin <-cut2(das$wt, g=3)

## View number of values in each bin
das %>% 
   count(count, bin) %>% 
   kable(align ='c')

## verify that bins have equal number of observations
| count |    bin    | n |
|:-----:|:---------:|:-:|
|   1   | [179,201) | 5 |
|   1   | [201,246) | 5 |
|   1   | [246,394] | 5 |
```

I then want to use the bin limits defined above to create bins for a second data frame, but I cannot figure out how to force the bins to be the same size:

```
das2 <- data.frame(anim=1:15, count = 1, wt=c(185,190,181,220,205,235,226,
                               189,304,303,179,205,199,394,231.3))
```

My end goal is to create a regression in k-fold cross validation by regressing the number of observations from 'das2' that fall in the bins created from 'das' -- I am trying to evaluate predictive strength of Resource Selection Functions generated under a used/available design from GPS Telemetry data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the intervals from the first cut to bin the second dataset, you can return them using the argument `onlycuts=TRUE` and feed them into the second call to `cut2`

```
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

das <- data.frame(anim=1:15, count = 1,
                  wt=c(181,179,180.5,201,201.5,245,246.4,
                       189.3,301,354,369,205,199,394,231.3))

das2 <- data.frame(anim=1:15, count = 1, wt=c(185,190,181,220,205,235,226,
                                              189,304,303,179,205,199,394,231.3))

breaks <-cut2(das$wt, g=3, onlycuts = TRUE)

das2$bin<-cut2(das2$wt, cuts = breaks)

das2 %>% 
  count(count, bin) %>% 
  kable(align ='c')

| count |    bin    | n |
|:-----:|:---------:|:-:|
|   1   | [179,201) | 6 |
|   1   | [201,246) | 6 |
|   1   | [246,394] | 3 |
```

Comment: in the event that the second data frame has a value outside of the range of the cuts generated by the first frame, is there a way let the first and last bins to be bounded by (-/+) infinite? For instance if Data frame two has a 'wt' value of 600 instead of 231.3, it will be put into its own bin

Comment: Sure, you can always just set `breaks[1]=-Inf` and/or
`breaks[length(breaks)]=Inf` after generating them.

Comment: Great, thank you. I had to set both of these conditions: `das_breaks <- cut2(das$wt, g=3, onlycuts = TRUE)
das_breaks[1] =-Inf
das_breaks[length(das_breaks)]=Inf`